# How to setup BitBucket in Intelilij Idea with only sourcecode, not module/project settings

Tags: git, intellij-idea, bitbucket

We are a small team of developers who are using the following setup at the moment

- everyone has a local Intelij Idea project on its own computer
- everyone uses the same network share with source code of the project which is configured in the modules of each project

Because we experience latency on loading files from network & VCS is needed we want to switch to git on Bitbucket.

I have tested with the BitBucket plugin but when i import the project into Bitbucket with the Idea-plugin it creates a repository including the module&project settings.

We do not want the module settings to be included because the paths to some modules differ between team members (Macs vs PC)

E.g this will work on Mac, but not in Win8

```
<content url="file:///Volumes/websites/develop/spCalendarix/backoffice/src">
  <sourceFolder url="file:///Volumes/websites/develop/spCalendarix/backoffice/src" isTestSource="false" />
</content>
```

I have added all *.iml files & directory .idea to the ignored filelist but the plugin keeps pushing these files to bitbucket.

What is the correct strategy to have a VCS for the sourcecode, but local module setup for each developer.

Or am I on the wrong track ?

thnx

Comment: I have no experience with IntelliJ, but in Eclipse you'd set project variables to represent the base of a module (or a whole set of modules) and use relative paths to that module. Each developer sets their own base path and away they go. Does IntelliJ have nothing similar?

Comment: thnx, just searched and found intelij idea has 'path variables' that do exactly the same.